# What is an IHC. word™?

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, language, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an **IHC. Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ IHC.}\ }
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[#fcce8d]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  women}&\text{       lady}\\ \hline
\text{  like}&\text{       love}\\ \hline
\text{  Bali}&\text{       Bintan}\\ \hline
\text{  nine}&\text{       ten}\\ \hline
\text{  mile}&\text{       kilometer}\\ \hline
\text{  Sudan}&\text{       Kenya}\\ \hline
\text{  side}&\text{       corner}\\ \hline
\text{  piping}&\text{       plumbing}\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}$$

CSV version:

```
IHC. Words™, Not IHC. Words™
women;lady
like;love
Bali;Bintan
nine;ten
mile;kilometer
Sudan;Kenya
side;corner
piping;plumbing
```

These are not the only examples of IHC. words™, many more exist. I'm sorry that I gave too few words but IHC. words™ are **REALLY** hard to find.
**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Hint 1:

> Nothing to do with English or anything like letters, vowels, etc.

Hint 2:

> More specifically, the language can ONLY be derived from the title

Hint 3:

> Think *backwards* (Referring to the title)

Comment: How did you create the grid?

Comment: Sice I don't know how to answer the puzzle, I'll just leave this here istead: CSV = _Comma_ separated values :P

Comment: @WilliamPennanti right click on the table and select "Show Math as" -> "Tex commands", or just click "edit" and have a look at the raw text of the puzzle.

Comment: @William Pennanti I also don’t know, I just copy pasted it from somewhere else

Comment: In light of your hint, does this puzzle need a 'language' tag?

Comment: @Stiv Added, thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An IHC. word is

> a word that forms a valid Mandarin word when read in [Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin#Initials_and_finals) phonetics

Example:

> Women --> Wǒmen --> 我们

Title hint:

> IHC backwards is CHI (Chinese)

Comment: Nice spot sedrick :) As well as 'women', could you list how the other IHC words meet this criterion? It would be interesting to see and would make for a nice well-rounded solution. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Good job finding the answer :)

Comment: @Stiv I'm actually not familiar with some of the Mandarin words in the clue since I'm not a native speaker. Also, with Mandarin, a pinyin word can correspond to many different characters. I'm actually also curious about some of the words, so if someone could fill it in, that would be great :)